# Regex work in chrome and explorer but not in firefox

Tags: regex

I am using Jquery to validate my textbox. my particular regex condition is...

```
/^[A-Za-z.-\s]*$/.. that is alphabets, space, hyphen, and dots.
```

Issue is it work great and efficiently in Chrome and explorer but firefox gives error for this regex. I checked using firebug. Even it also not work for firefox.

```
Error: invalid range in character class
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid the hyphen having a special meaning (range of characters) you should put it at the end of the character class:

```
[A-Za-z.\s-]
```

Alternatively you can escape it:

```
[A-Za-z.\-\s]
```

Comment: He should also escape the period, or it will match any character.

Comment: @Walkerneo: The period is literal when inside a character class. It does not need escaping here.

Comment: #mark byers: What should be expression for remove double repeat ofspace, dots and hyphen.. I mean I want to remove \s\s,..,--. It may -a-, a , .a-, or else.... or it may be anything but not repeatation of these three particulars.

Answer (score 1):

Escape the hyphen:

`/^[A-Za-z.\-\s]*$/`